# How do I get no padding for my bootstrap grid?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, grid, padding

Here is my webpage

www.cosmic.chillcastle.com

I would like to eliminate padding all together.

I have been using css but does not seem to be doing it. Also, in mobile it looks great oriented vertically but stacks weird horizontally.

I have tried to use css to individually correct each element to have no padding.

here's the grid code Im using.

```
 <div class="col-1-3">
 <div class="module">

<img class="img-responsive" src="cosmicveggie-banner2_02.jpg" width:"100%" >        
 </div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="col-1-3">
 <div class="module">

<img class="img-responsive" src="cosmicveggie-banner2_03.jpg" width:"100%" >        
 </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Please post the relevant code instead of an external link. The external site doesn't seem to be using the Bootstrap grid and instead referencing css classes in dog2.css

Comment: Hey @zimsystem added the bootstrap code I am using. Does that help?

Comment: No too much as `col-1-3` and `module` aren't Bootstrap classes so it seems to have nothing to do with "no padding for my bootstrap grid"

Answer (score 0):

@dunnj515 ,  @zimsystem Thanks, I ended up scrapping the whole lay out and doing this:

```
 <div class="row">

 <div class="col-sm-4" > 
 <img class="img-responsive" src="cosmicveggie-banner2_01.jpg" width:"100%" >
</div>

<div class="col-sm-4" > <img class="img-responsive" src="cosmicveggie-banner2_02.jpg" width:"100%" ></div>
<div class="col-sm-4"> <img class="img-responsive" src="cosmicveggie-banner2_03.jpg" width:"100%" ></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Like ZimSystem mentioned col-1-3 and module aren't Bootstrap classes. The Bootstrap grid is arranged into rows and columns which need to be inside a container. So your overall structure would need to look something like this:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="cosmicveggie-banner1.jpg" width:"100%" >
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="cosmicveggie-banner2.jpg" width:"100%" >
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="cosmicveggie-banner3.jpg" width:"100%" >
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Checkout this [explanation in the documentation](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/).